# Android　SDK23におけるGPS取得

Tags: android, gps

Android　の位置情報取得についてです

http://techbooster.jpn.org/andriod/application/2525/
http://seesaawiki.jp/w/moonlight_aska/d/%B0%CC%C3%D6%BE%F0%CA%F3%A4%F2%BC%E8%C6%C0%A4%B9%A4%EB

などGPS取得のサンプルは多くありますがSDK23に対応したソースサンプルはほとんどありません
checkSelfPermission　に対応したサンプルコードの記載、またはその例の記載のあるサイトを教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android SDK23のPermissionはRuntimeでリクエストが必要になります。

リクエスト方法の例は：

```
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
            //ユーザーになぜ位置情報取得の許可が必要を説明して、リクエストします。
            Snackbar.make(contentView, R.string.access_location_permission_description, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(KamelioLoginActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                    }
                }).show();
        } else {
            //ユーザーにしましたが、まだ許可されてないのでまたリクエストします。
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(KamelioLoginActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
```

リクエストの結果はonRequestPermissionsResultにでます：

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //許可されました。
            } else {
                //許可されなかったので、メッセージ表示します。
                Snackbar.make(contentView, R.string.access_location_permission_not_granted,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```